# Need keyboard with key markings that don't wear off

Tags: keyboard, usb-keyboard

I am constantly replacing keyboards because the keytop markings wear off after a year or so, although otherwise the keyboards work fine.  Back in the day, key markings were molded though and never wore off.  All I can find these days are keyboards with silkscreened tops, and these never last.

Can anyone recommend a basic standard 105-key keyboard with molded through keys?

Comment: You're gonna have to fork out some money if you want quality.

Comment: How much are you spending on these keyboards? I've never had this problem with any keyboard I've ever used. If you buy a good quality mechanical or even non-mechanical keyboard, you should not have this problem

Comment: @DrZoo Most keyboards I've seen do seem to wear off the letters eventually, from the el cheapo practically free ones included with desktops up to [MS's Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000/b2m-00012)

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic. It can be on topic on [Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Apple keyboards are moulded through - the separate USB/Bluetooth ones for certain, idk about the laptop ones. I got 8 years out of my last one before the e started to fade.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

- Paint over the letters with clear paint (clear nail polish works great) so there's a protective coating that would hopefully wear down before the letters do.
- Invest in a cheap white marker or paint pen, and draw the letters back on when they wear off.

  - Or draw the letters on the front (side) of the keys, so you're not pressing on the letter. Or put letter stickers there.
- Buy any keyboard with a warranty that covers letters wearing off, and exchange/return it.
- Wear soft gloves while typing (*fancy!*)
- Memorize the keys so you don't care if they wear off.